# Preparing PDF file for black and white offset newspaper print

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, pdf, color-conversion, prepress

The print shop is asking me for a PDF in CMYK colors even though they will use only black ink for printing.

My pages are originally laid out in color. Should I simply convert the page to grayscale and export PSD as PDF with PDF/X-1a:2001? Because now my black is like composite 44.55.44.80 and not 0.0.0.100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should save your file as CMYK (With all data in the K channel) as requested. So after your conversion to greyscale choose:

`Edit` > `Convert to Profile...`

Under `Destination Space` tick `CMYK` then choose `profile` `Custom CMYK...`

Set `Black Generation` to `Maximum` to make sure the greyscale image moves to the `Black` channel only.

[image]

Note that if your printer asks for a specific max black ink limit, you can set it here too.

Now you have a CMYK file where all black sits in the K channel only. Now you can save to PDF/X-1a:2001 just keep in mind that you don't want to convert any values!